# Convert DataTable Row To DataGridView Row

Tags: c#

I have a DataTable filled out from a database and I need to add to the data GridView specific Rows from the DataTable according to a condition (if statement).

I have the following code but it does not work and I could not make casting from DataTable Row To DataGridViewRow.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i][5].ToString()) < Convert.ToDateTime("00:05:00"))
                    {  
                        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dt.Rows[i]);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
DataRow[] rows = dt.Select("NameOfColumn < '00:05:00'");
dataGridView1.DataSource = rows.CopyToDataTable();
```

With "`NameOfColumn`" represent for you  "`dt.Rows[i][5]`";

Comment: Thanks Beldi. It is such another good way. but there is only small edit to your code then it works pretty well.

dt.Select(" NameOfColumn <  00:05:00 '")

Answer (score 2):

[`DataGridView.Rows.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows(v=vs.110).aspx) method accepts array of objects as a parameter.

So you could add rows to DatagridView using `ItemArray` property of a `DataRow`.

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray);
```

Comment: Thanks Hari. it works, but I needed to add the columns at first then add the rows.

Comment: That's correct, in reality you could directly set DataTable as DataSource. You don't need to add it explicit unless there is explicit demand.